# Optimal Transport between two Gaussians

Tags: normal-distribution, optimal-transport, wasserstein

Consider the optimal transport map $T$ between $N(\mu_0,\Sigma_0)$ and $N(\mu_1,\Sigma_1)$. I believed that the optimal transport was given by:

$$ T(x) = \mu_1 + \Sigma_1^{1/2} \Sigma_0^{-1/2}(x-\mu_0) $$

However in Peyre's book "Computational optimal transport" and other resources they claim that the map is:

$$T(x) = \mu_1 + (\Sigma_0^{-1/2}(\Sigma_0^{1/2}\Sigma_1 \Sigma_0^{1/2})^{1/2} \Sigma_0^{-1/2})(x-\mu_0) $$

I was wondering what is wrong with the transport I wrote.

#### My attempt

To prove that the proposed map works I used the Monge-Ampere equation. It is a straight forward calculation and everything works nicely.

Comment: See the "Quadratic normal case" here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transportation_theory_(mathematics)#Quadratic_normal_case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that for $T(x)$ to be optimal it has to be the gradient of a convex function $\phi(x).$ In your case if $T$ is the gradient of a function $\phi$ then
$$
\Delta \phi  = \Sigma_1^{1/2}\Sigma_0^{-1/2},
$$
but this matrix won't be in general positive definite or symmetric. Therefore you are considering cannot be optimal.